# Changing size of ImageView inside ScrollView crash the applications

Tags: android, android-studio, scrollview

I am just a beginner at android studio.So bear with me guys
I am creating a android app with ScrollView. my code worked well in the beginning,I could scroll through the screen.(I have 3 ImageView widgets inside the scroll view of each size 70dp x 70dp) but when i changed the size of the each image to 300dp X 200dp the app crashes :(

Here is my working code :

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:fillViewport="false">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="231dp"
                    android:layout_height="58dp"
                    android:textSize="60dp"
                    android:text="TEXT"
                    android:textColor="#e0b122"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="115dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Small text"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:id="@+id/textView5"
                    android:textSize="30dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="text....................................text"
                    android:textColor="#e0b122"
                    android:id="@+id/textView6" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/image1"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="text"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:id="@+id/textView7"
                    android:textSize="30dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="text....................................text"
                    android:textColor="#e0b122"
                    android:id="@+id/textView8" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/image2"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:id="@+id/imageView5"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Text"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:id="@+id/textView9"
                    android:textSize="30dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="text....................................text"
                    android:textColor="#e0b122"
                    android:id="@+id/textView10"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/image3"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:id="@+id/imageView6"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

But When i change the size of ImageView to 70dp X 70dp the appication crash
Eg.

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:src="@drawable/image3"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView6"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"/>
```

Comment: @F43nd1r logs ? I din't got that. my bad 
Just a beginner

Comment: Works with 70dp and crashes with 300dp? thats so strange. Please post the logcat output, Exception stacktrace or whatever you call it.

Comment: @MayooghGirish : If you are using Android studio, once you get Unfortunately your application stopped working , go to View --> Tool Windows --> Android/Android Monitor click on it :) You will see a window with log level filter select Error :) and print whatever you can see in red color text :)

Comment: @SandeepBhandari i am getting this error when i clicked Android Monitor 
 " Unable to obtain result of 'adb version' "

Comment: @Mayoogh Girish : Sorry buddy :) Never had this issue before, No idea :| But this is how you can get the logs people are asking you to paste and without log people wont be able to help you much :( Lets see somebody might help you to get reolve with this error :)

Comment: please post your error log...complete error log

Comment: Firstly run the app... when your app unfortunately stop then check Android Monitor without click on unfortunately stop dialog ...

Answer (score 0):

try this :-

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:padding="10dp">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="TEXT"
        android:textColor="#e0b122"
        android:textSize="60dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="Small text"
        android:textSize="30dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="text....................................text"
        android:textColor="#e0b122" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/image1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="text"
        android:textSize="30dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="text....................................text"
        android:textColor="#e0b122" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/image2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="text"
        android:textSize="30dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="text....................................text"
        android:textColor="#e0b122" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView10"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/image3" />
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Replace It**

```
<ImageView
android:layout_width="350dp"
android:layout_height="250dp"
android:src="@drawable/image3"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
android:id="@+id/imageView6"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:layout_marginRight="20dp"/>
```

**With**

```
<ImageView
android:layout_width="70dp"
android:layout_height="70dp"
android:src="@drawable/image3"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
android:id="@+id/imageView6"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
```

**hope It will help you...**

Comment: I want somewhat larger image

Comment: then Increase **android:layout_width="70dp"
android:layout_height="70dp"** more then **70 dp**

Comment: your app is again crush or not??